# populating <select> tag with PHP

Tags: php, html, for-loop, drop-down-menu

I am trying to dynamically populate a select tag in php, by printing values from an array of objects.

this is my code

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($z); $i++)
{
    print('<option value ="'.$z[i]->getId().'">'.$z[i]->getDescription().'</option>');
}
```

the array is populated, in fact if i try to print only the fields i get a result, but in the combo-box nothing appears

Comment: where is your select tag?

Comment: If you had error reporting enabled, you would see the errors in the code.

Comment: what is `$z`? an array?

Comment: Have you made sure you have error reporting turned on? Also, while developing, you should enable `display_errors`.  Also, please edit your question to include _all: the correct code (you posted updated code as an answer recently, which you then removed). Do some proper debugging and dump the variables you have to see if they contain what you expect: `var_dump($z):`

Answer (score 1):

*Replace `i` with `$i`*

```
<select name="name">
  <?php
  for($i = 0; $i < count($z); $i++)
  {
    print('<option value ="'.$z[$i]->getId().'">'.$z[$i]->getDescription().'</option>');
  }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add select tag and replace `i` with `$i`

```
echo "<select>";
for($i = 0; $i < count($z); $i++) {
    echo '<option value ="'.$z[$i]->getId().'">'.$z[$i]->getDescription().'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i resolved by creating two support arrays

```
$ids = array();
$descs = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($z); $i++) {
    $ids[$i] = $z[$i]->getId();
    $descs[$i] = $z[$i]->getDescritpion();
}
```

and using them instead of the objects

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($z); $i++) {
     print('<option value ="' . $ids[$i] . '">' . $descs[$i] . '</option>');
}
```

not very efficient, but working.
thanks for the answer :)